# OpenStreetMap offline tiles - licensing issue

Tags: geolocation, devexpress, maps, geospatial, openstreetmap

In my application, I want to bind Devexpress WPF Map control to a bunch of tiles. I do not need any deep zoom level - something up to 5-6 zoom levels would be acceptable.

Is it allowed to legally download such tiles from OpenStreetMap?

Thanks!

Comment: You checked out http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ ?

Beside that, keep in mind that your tool might have a lifecycle and thus the tiles need to be updated from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tiles produced by the main OSM tile server are **CC-BY-SA-2 licensed** so you are legally able to download them, share them, etc, as long as you abide by the standard Creative Commons licensing requirements (such as [the attribution statement](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ#3a._I_would_like_to_use_OpenStreetMap_maps._How_should_I_credit_you.3F)).

However, when accessing the tileserver you must abide by the [**tile usage policy** shown here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) - in particular, **"bulk downloading is strongly discouraged"** because of the bandwidth impact.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy

Comment: Regarding the bulk downloadig: Because OpenStreetMap provides free *data* you can just [render your own tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) instead, for example by using TileMill or Maperitive.